# TypeError: Repository method is not a function (NestJS / TypeORM)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm working with NestJS and TypeORM. When trying to call the createMailLogEntry method of the repository, I'm getting the following error: `TypeError: this.mailLogEntryRepository.createMailLogEntry is not a function`

I can't figure out what's going wrong.

**mailing.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class MailingService {

    constructor(@InjectRepository(MailLogEntryRepository) private mailLogEntryRepository: MailLogEntryRepository) { }

        // ...

        if(transferResult) {
            await this.mailLogEntryRepository.createMailLogEntry({
                creationDate: new Date(Date.now()),
                from: mailContent.from,
                to: mailContent.to,
                subject: mailContent.subject,
                text: mailContent.text,
                html: mailContent.html,
                cc: mailContent.cc,
                bcc: mailContent.bcc,
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**mail-log-entry.repository.ts**

```
@EntityRepository(MailLogEntry)
export class MailLogEntryRepository extends Repository<MailLogEntry> {

    async createMailLogEntry(mailLogEntryDto: MailLogEntryDto): Promise<MailLogEntry> {
        const mailLogEntry = MailLogEntryRepository.createMailLogEntryFromDto(mailLogEntryDto);
        return await mailLogEntry.save();
    }

    private static createMailLogEntryFromDto(mailLogEntryDto: MailLogEntryDto): MailLogEntry {
        const mailLogEntry = new MailLogEntry();
        mailLogEntry.from = mailLogEntryDto.from;
        mailLogEntry.to = mailLogEntryDto.to;
        mailLogEntry.subject = mailLogEntryDto.subject;
        mailLogEntry.text = mailLogEntryDto.text;
        mailLogEntry.html = mailLogEntryDto.html;
        mailLogEntry.cc = mailLogEntryDto.cc;
        mailLogEntry.bcc = mailLogEntryDto.bcc;

        return mailLogEntry;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably you have some problem how you provide this custom repository and your mailing service gets undefined in place of mailLogEntryRepository

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I came across this problem as well.
Make sure you're importing the repository into the module.

Here's what your module should probably look like.

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([TeamRepository])],
  providers: [TeamService],
  controllers: [TeamController]
})
export class TeamModule {}
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, I'll tell you what got me out of it if it helps someone else!

If your repository is handmade (not generated by an ORM) then you can't use the Repository injection :

[image: Inject repository Image 1]

Instead just use the repository as you would for a service (just remove the @InjectRepository(People)):

[image: Inject repository image 2]

I hope this will help!Happy coding !

PS : Personnes is my entity and the helper has nothing to do with the issue

Answer (score 6):

In new TypeORM version(0.3.*), changed custom repositories to services https://typeorm.io/custom-repository and it's a little different approach so current code using **@EntityRepository(MyEntity)** will don't work. Can be a nightmare migrate all functions from something like this:

```js
exampleQueryBuilder() {
    return this.createQueryBuilder() ...
}
```

to this:

```js
exampleQueryBuilder() {
    return this.dataSource
          .getRepository(Person)
          .createQueryBuilder() ...
}
```

apart from the rest of the changes. It's possible to implement a custom repository in the following way utilizing DataSource and seems simple for me:

```js
// account.repository.ts
@Injectable()
export class AccountsRepository extends Repository<AccountsEntity> {
    constructor(private dataSource: DataSource) {
        super(AccountsEntity, dataSource.createEntityManager());
    }

    async getByUsername(username: string) {
        return this.findOne({ where: { username } });
    }
    // ...
}
```

The repository is then injected into the service.

```js
// account.service.ts
export class AccountService {
    constructor(private readonly accountRepository: AccountRepository) {}

    async getByUsername(username: string): Promise<Account> {
        return this.accountRepository.getByUsername(username);
    }
    // ...
}
```

and the module has imports for the feature and the repository as a provider.

```js
// account.module.ts
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([AccountEntity])],
    // ...
  ],
    providers: [AccountService, AccountRepository],
    // ...
})
export class AccountModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help too, it's related with @Simple Dev answer about handmade repository. For example if you create an Entity, Service and Repositoy classes with different names probably when you try to call a repository member function from service will be undefined. Ex:

```
@Entity
export class Person { ... }

@Injectable()
export class OtherPersonService { ... }  // Person !== OtherPerson

@EntityRepository(Person)
export class OtherPersonRepository extends Repository<Person> { ... } // Same problem
```

I came across this problem as well, after rename my service and repository the error is gone. For the previous example the solution would be: **Person**, **PersonService** and **PersonRepository**.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was that I've imported the entity and the custom repository for that entity together.

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
  TeamRepository,
  Team   // either the entity or the custom repository should be imported.
  ])],
  providers: [TeamService],
  controllers: [TeamController]
})
export class TeamModule {}
```

Comment: @Noniq, I'm currently having this same issue and none of these answers are fixing it for me. I don't know if you ever got yours fixed or if anyone has a fix for this. It's exactly the same issue saying  **TypeError: this.userRepository.register is not a function**

Comment: @MSadiq Have you solved it?

Comment: Yes, I just added what fixed it for me to the answers, hopefully it helps someone someday

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. The custom extended repository you make has to be imported via Typeorm like in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I'll leave this here hoping it might help someone. You can eliminate having the ***repository*** file and use **@InjectRepository** on the constructor of your service. Then you can access all the repository methods on your service. Make sure to include your entity on **TypeOrmModule.forFeature** on the imports of your module.

Here **Product** is my entity and this is my service file (ProductService) which I call from the controller.
Happy coding!

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
 private logger = new Logger('ProductService');
 constructor(
  @InjectRepository(Product)
  private productRepository: Repository<Product>
 ) { }

 async getAllAsync(): Promise<Product[]> {
  return await this.productRepository.find();
 }

 async getCountAsync(): Promise<number> {
  return await this.productRepository.count();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@MFuat,
Yes, finally fixed it this morning, mine was also related to unit testing the **user.service.ts** file. Turns out I wasn't mocking the register method in my test file. so once I mocked it,the test passed.

```
const mockUserRepository = {
  register: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('sampleResolvedValue')
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import repository into Providers, not in `TypeOrmModule.forFeature`

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
      YourEntity
    ])
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [YourRepository],
  exports: [],
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I came across this issue before.
and it was saying that the function is Undefined.
I tried so many solutions but with no luck
and then I just changed the repo name from payment to payments
and it worked with me.
so try to change the repo name